# Update Variable with javascript after chart has been loaded - amcharts

Tags: javascript, json, global-variables

I need to update the data in a number of JSON arrays by using a select menu.

**The idea is this:** 
Select a year which updates a global variable (JSON Array)  with data associated with that year.

My problem is I am not sure about variable scope and how to get control of this. I am also finding that amcharts builds the charts onload so updating a variable wouldn'd do anything

Is it possible to update a global variable with a new data set and then reload the charts with the new data? What would this look like?

Not sure this update helps or if this is any more clear.

Here is a link to a fiddle of one of the charts I built:

http://jsfiddle.net/kenaesthetic/33JH9/

**The shorthand structure goes like this:**

```
<head>
<script> amchart script </script>  
<head>

<body>

<select>
<option>2010</option
<option>2011</option
<option>2012</option
<option>2013</option
<option>2014</option
</select>

<div id="chart-container-1"></div> // These charts are stacked (refer to the fiddle)
<div id="chart-container-2"></div>
<div id="chart-container-3"></div>
<div id="chart-container-4"></div>
<div id="chart-container-5"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do something more like this:

```
var chart;

var chartData = [
    {
        "subject": "Personal Services",
        "2010": 493142064,
        "2011": 540156996,
        "2012": 593541335,
        "2013": 640585618,
        "2014": 689417065
    }
];

AmCharts.ready(function () {
    // SERIALL CHART
    chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
    chart.categoryField = "subject";
    chart.plotAreaBorderAlpha = 0.2;
    chart.rotate = true;

    // AXES
    // Category
    var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
    categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
    categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
    categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";

    // value                      
    var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
    valueAxis.stackType = "regular";
    valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
    valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
    chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

    // GRAPHS
    // firstgraph 
    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.title = "2010";
    graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
    graph.valueField = "2010";
    graph.type = "column";
    graph.lineAlpha = 0;
    graph.fillAlphas = 1;
    graph.lineColor = "#C72C95";
    graph.balloonText = "<b><span style='color:#C72C95'>[[title]]</b></span><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>";
    chart.addGraph(graph);

    // second graph                              
    graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.title = "2011";
    graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
    graph.valueField = "2011";
    graph.type = "column";
    graph.lineAlpha = 0;
    graph.fillAlphas = 1;
    graph.lineColor = "#D8E0BD";
    graph.balloonText = "<b><span style='color:#afbb86'>[[title]]</b></span><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>";
    chart.addGraph(graph);

    // third graph              
    graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.title = "2012";
    graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
    graph.valueField = "2012";
    graph.type = "column";
    graph.lineAlpha = 0;
    graph.fillAlphas = 1;
    graph.lineColor = "#B3DBD4";
    graph.balloonText = "<b><span style='color:#74bdb0'>[[title]]</b></span><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>";
    chart.addGraph(graph);

    // fourth graph 
    graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.title = "2013";
    graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
    graph.valueField = "2013";
    graph.type = "column";
    graph.lineAlpha = 0;
    graph.fillAlphas = 1;
    graph.lineColor = "#69A55C";
    graph.balloonText = "<b><span style='color:#69A55C'>[[title]]</b></span><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>";
    chart.addGraph(graph);

    // fifth graph 
    graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.title = "2014";
    graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
    graph.valueField = "2014";
    graph.type = "column";
    graph.lineAlpha = 0;
    graph.fillAlphas = 1;
    graph.lineColor = "#B5B8D3";
    graph.balloonText = "<b><span style='color:#7a81be'>[[title]]</b></span><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>";
    chart.addGraph(graph);

    // LEGEND
    var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
    legend.position = "right";
    legend.borderAlpha = 0.3;
    legend.horizontalGap = 10;
    legend.switchType = "v";
    chart.addLegend(legend);

    // WRITE
    chart.write("chartdiv");
});

// Make chart 2D/3D
function setDepth() {
    if (document.getElementById("rb1").checked) {
        chart.depth3D = 0;
        chart.angle = 0;
    } else {
        chart.depth3D = 20;
        chart.angle = 30;
    }
    chart.validateNow();
}
```

This example is based on the AmChart's example code for stacked chart. It does separate out the data for the chart into a global Javascript variable, namely chartData.

You need to break down the problem into two parts: the manipulation of the data and then loading the data into the chart after it has been changed.

Here is very simple example of manipulating the data using jQuery and a button. http://jsfiddle.net/stevewilhelm/XzmQ6/2/

Once the data is modified, you will need to update the chart. See http://blog.amcharts.com/2013/08/tutorial-live-editing-chart-data.html as an example.

And look at chart.dataProvider chart.validateData() for details.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I tried writing it like this before but was unsuccessful so I wrote it longhand. You also aren't addressing the problem. Was I not clear about what I am trying to learn. This is helpful though of you can create a fiddle and get it to work.

Comment: Modified answer above.

Comment: Nice thanks. I will need the time to mess with this but I can see it works.